# How to iterate object which contains array in one field in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I want to display some records in html file in my angular project.
i am getting response-

```
tabledata = {
   "employeeId":12345678,
   "employeeName":"John",
   "VehicleNumber": "LA99DU3267",
   "city":"Toronto", 
   "events":[
      {
         "date":"05/01/20",
         "inTime":"01:09:45",
         "OutTime":"05:13:50",       
         "hoursSpent": 20,           
      },
      {
         "date":"05/01/21",
         "inTime":"02:09:45",
         "OutTime":"06:13:50",       
         "hoursSpent": 30,
      },
      {
         "date":"05/01/22",
         "inTime":"03:09:45",
         "OutTime":"07:13:50",       
         "hoursSpent": 10,       
      },
      {
         "date":"05/01/23",
         "inTime":"04:09:45",
         "OutTime":"08:13:50",       
         "hoursSpent": 40,       
      },
   ],
}
```

I want to display data in a table like below-

```
Empid   empname     vehicle       city      date       intime     outtime     hoursSpent
john    12345678   LA99DU3267    Toronto   05/01/20    01:09:45   05:13:50     20
john    12345678   LA99DU3267    Toronto   05/01/21    02:09:45   06:13:50     30
john    12345678   LA99DU3267    Toronto   05/01/22    03:09:45   07:13:50     10
john    12345678   LA99DU3267    Toronto   05/01/23    04:09:45   08:13:50     40
```

i am able to display values from array which is inside array by using-

```
<ion-row class="data-table data-table-row" *ngFor="let data of tableData.events"> 
    <ion-col class="ion-text-center cell-class" *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue: originalOrder">
         {{ item.key  }}
     </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

but to display values which is in object i am not getting any solution.

PLease help.
Thanks in advance
**If someone going to mark it negative please do so but please first help me**

Maybe this is a silly question but i am new to angular so this is really big for me.

Comment: do you want to know how to use the `keyvalue` pipe to get the value of the object's properties?

Comment: i exactly don't know how to use keyvalue pipe but got this solution while trying to iterate over object

Comment: Those be be directly accessed using the tabledata. For eg. tabledata.employeeName

Comment: those value can be directly accessed but i need to access array value also in same row of table. how can i start my for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom pipe to transform your data  and get it displayed

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
  name:'datamap'
})
export class DataMapPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(val,arg){
    return val.map(event =>{
    const { events, ...otherProps } = arg;
     return {
       ...event,
       ...otherProps
     } 
    })
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ion-row class="data-table data-table-row" *ngFor="let data of tableData.events | datamap:tableData"> 
    <ion-col class="ion-text-center cell-class" *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue: originalOrder">
         {{ item.key  }}
     </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

I have no idea about ionic i believe this can be helpful

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvfbum)